# Usar if com matrizes

Tags: c, matriz, if

A pergunta acaba sendo até logicamente fácil, mas estou com dificuldade de saber como utilizar a condição if nos valores da matriz, não sei como fazer para mexer com os valores da matriz. meu código ficou logo abaixo mas eu fico perdido em como encaixar o if

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```c
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {

float MatOriginal[3][5],MatFinal[3][5];

// entrada de dados
printf("escreva os valores da matriz original: \n");
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
  printf("elemento (%d)(%d)",i+1,j+1);
  scanf("%f",&MatOriginal[i][j]);
}
  }
  if(MatOriginal[3][5]<0)
    MatOriginal[3][5] = - MatOriginal[3][5]
// escrita da matriz
printf(" \n A matriz original informada é = \n");
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  printf(" \n ");
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
     printf(" %4.1f ", MatOriginal[i][j]);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro vou reformatar o seu código para ficar bem visível. Vou tirar a parte onde você colocou o `if` porque estava errado:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {

    float MatOriginal[3][5], MatFinal[3][5];

    // entrada de dados
    printf("escreva os valores da matriz original: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("elemento (%d)(%d)", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%f", &MatOriginal[i][j]);
            // *** Colocar aqui.
        }
    }

    // escrita da matriz
    printf(" \n A matriz original informada é = \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf(" \n ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf(" %4.1f ", MatOriginal[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Antes de mais nada, há um problema no segundo bloco de laços `for`. Lá, você tinha que mostrar a matriz nova, e não a matriz original.

O lugar onde você tem que colocar o `if` é onde está o `// *** Colocar aqui`. O que você tem que fazer é o seguinte: Use o `if` para comparar se o valor de `MatOriginal[i][j]` é maior ou igual a 0. Se for maior ou igual a zero, copie para `MatOriginal[i][j]` para `MatFinal[i][j]`. Caso contrário, copie para `-MatOriginal[i][j]` para `MatFinal[i][j]`.